# How to build and push multi platform docker images

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I built docker image for arm64 platform on my x86 Intel laptop with following command:

```
docker buildx build . --progress plain --platform linux/arm64/v8 -t myimage:0.4 &> docker-build.log
```

Log file had no error and the build process seem to have completed successfully. I wanted to push this image to docker hub. But when I checked the image with `docker images` and `docker image ls` commands, both command outputs did not contained above image (`myimage:0.4`).

Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#output) says:

> In `docker build` all builds finish by creating a container image and exporting it to `docker images`. `buildx` makes this step configurable allowing results to be exported directly to the client, oci image tarballs, registry etc.

But then it says the `docker` export type writes the single-platform result image as a Docker image specification tarball on the client.

So I have couple of questions:

1. How can I build multi platform (amd64 and arm64) image and push it to dockerhub? Is adding `--push` only option? Or I can export them to local file say with `--output tar` and then somehow push them to docker hub? (I tried `--output tar --push`. But it gave error that we cannot use `local` and push together!)
2. Did I lost the arm64 image that I just build? Can I export it now to tar and push it to dockerhub?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker BuildX image not showing in docker image ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403659/docker-buildx-image-not-showing-in-docker-image-ls)

Comment: No. It does not answer 1. if `--push` is the only option 2. If I have lost my currently built image.